# I have a tab bar with 4 tabs, i wants to validate all the tabs data from main class? how to achieve it in flutter with Provider

Tags: flutter, provider

Class A has 4 tabs, each tab has its own classes and fields, is there a elegant way to validate all the classes/tabs from Class A using Provider architecture.

Comment: What's your mean from validate!?

Comment: My idea here is, that the main Page collects the inputs from all Tabs and check if everything is ok and take user to Summary Page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official tutorial documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). It's going to explain step by step how to create a model that shares states between other widgets.

I've also made the prototype below and a [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1e4f50b5e6ef8782a1e838587108434f) to help you out with your exact problem.

| Data | A | B | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No Data | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| With Data | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Below is the code from DartPad as a [minimum-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is the `Model` provider where the data resides for every widget to access it. The classes `A`, `B`, and `Summary` each one consumes the `Model` data using the [Consumer<Model>](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html). Every time the `Model` changes it notifies all consumers (the listeners) of the change and then the widgets can be updated with the new data.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

enum BEnum {
  test1,
  test2,
}

class Model extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _aText = '';
  BEnum? _bEnum;

  String get aText => _aText;
  BEnum? get bEnum => _bEnum;

  setText(String text) {
    _aText = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setBEnum(BEnum? bEnum) {
    _bEnum = bEnum;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Model()),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _selectedIndex = 0;

  final _tabs = [
    const A(),
    const B(),
    const Summary(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Center(child: _tabs[_selectedIndex]),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: 'A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.bolt), label: 'B'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list), label: 'Summary'),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class A extends StatelessWidget {
  const A({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text(
          'A',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Consumer<Model>(
          builder: (context, model, child) {
            return TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'A',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) => model.setText(value),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class B extends StatelessWidget {
  const B({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Model>(
      builder: (context, model, _) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'B',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: BEnum.values.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final bEnum = BEnum.values[index];
                  return RadioListTile<BEnum?>(
                    title: Text(bEnum.name),
                    groupValue: model.bEnum,
                    value: bEnum,
                    onChanged: (value) => model.setBEnum(value),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Summary extends StatelessWidget {
  const Summary({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Model>(
      builder: (context, model, _) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Summary',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text('A text: ',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(model.aText),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text('B selection: ',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(model.bEnum?.name ?? 'None'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```